# ROS2: how to create an Int8MultiArray

Tags: c++, arrays, ros2, uint8array

**This is a ROS2 beginner question**

I've tried to use several ROS sources which suggested me to include "std_msgs/Int8MultiArray.h".
However, if I do that I will get an error that is

```
fatal error: std_msgs/Int8MultiArray: No such file or directory
compilation terminated
```

What is the correct way to use array-like structure in ROS2? If there is a similar hpp header, where should I reference it?

Thank you! Any advice will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: What code are you trying to compile? Please include the code in the post.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include this in your code to work :

```cpp
#include "std_msgs/msg/u_int8_multi_array.hpp"
```

Comment: This is already an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ROS1 or ROS2 and what are your sources written for? The error you gave is in the format of a ROS1 message. If you're trying to import a ROS2 message it should look like this:

```
#include "std_msgs/msg/UInt8MultiArray"
```

Notice that there is an extra `msg` directory that isn't present for ROS1 messages.

Comment: it should also be snake_case